# Mvc: Alternative for form collection to better handle huge amount of parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form that has just 3 fields and I am writing this 
to a database by passing the values using a form collection to
the business layer.

Assuming I have 35 fields on my form and wants to write this 
to the database. Is there a better way of doing this than 
listing 35 fields in my code. I want to reduce the amount of code
I write.

```
    [HttpPost]
    Public ActionResult Create(FormCollection objFrmCollect)
    {
      Employee employee = new Employee();
      employee.Name = objFrmCollect["Name"];
      employee.Gender = objFrmCollect["Gender"];
      employee.City = objFrmCollect["City"];

      EmployeeBusinessLayer empBus = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();
      empBus.AddEmployee(employee);

      return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Comment: Why would you ever use `FormCollection`? It should be `public ActionResult Create(Employee model)` (and ditto for any other model you use)

Answer (score 1):

You should use Model Binder like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
```

It will automatically populate employee model with posted values.

Here is more information about model binding:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol

Answer (score 0):

Automatic conversion of form collection to a model class can't be direct. So the best way you should use is from the view where you are fetching the form collection, you should use directly model properties. i.e. you should bind it to a model.
So the alternative for form collection to handle huge amount of parameters is binding it to model